# Updating to windows 10 without an icon in the toolbar

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

How can I update my Sony Vaio notebook with German Windows 7 Home Premium to Windows 10 when it doesn't show an icon in the toolbar? All updates are installed.

When I use http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install it asks for a Windows 10 key which I don't have. I would want to use my existing Win 7 key.

Comment: At which point does it ask you for a key? Did you select the Upgrade option first?

Comment: @MC10: Yes, I selected the update section. Then I let the computer alone for the night downloading the update and doing whatever it can and the next morning the screen that asks for the key is there.

Comment: What happens if you don't give it a key and continue/skip?

Comment: If the installer is asking for a key then you are not getting the free upgrade, unless you have done the in-place upgrade once already, use the media creation tool and select "upgrade now"

Comment: @Ramhound : I'm using the update now feature of the Media Creation tool I linked.

Comment: Usually if it asks for a key you are trying to install the wrong version of W10, ie, trying to upgrade to Pro on W7 Home, it has to be same version for it to be free upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue did boil down to the fact that I tried to update my German version with an English version. Instead of telling me the English version simply pretended that no valid version exists.

When I installed the German version it worked.

Answer (score 0):

With all the updates installed you should get the needed version: Windows 7 SP1 which is the one that gets the upgrade app.

There might be some updates unselected/left behind of those needed for the app to be rightly handled. At least:

- support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3035583 and
- support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2952664

See that the windows update doesn't have anything pending.

If that didn't make it happen, you may download the app yourself ([article from Microsoft support](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/i-want-to-reserve-my-free-copy-of-windows-10-but-i/848b5cce-958b-49ae-a132-a999a883265b?auth=1))

(source: http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/dont-see-the-windows-10-upgrade-notification-heres-what-to-do/)

Comment: As I said in the text. I did install all the updates (windows update doesn't have anything pending).

Comment: Nice. So with Windows 7 Service Pack 1, you may attempt to download the Windows 10 app by hand. Any luck?